# What can I ask Siri on macOS?

Tags: macos, siri

So some things I figured out already like open this file/folder/app etc.

What more can I ask Siri on my MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Siri can do all kinds of things, like alter system settings, open applications, check storage on iCloud, and more. Here’s what [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2016/09/28/use-mac-siri-commands/) has gathered up so far, though some of these double-over on iOS as well:

- Put my computer to sleep
- Activate the screen saver
- Make the screen brighter
- Make the screen dimmer
- Is Bluetooth on?
- Turn Bluetooth off / on
- Lower the volume
- Increase the volume
- Show me privacy settings
- Show me location settings
- Show me network settings
- What is my desktop wallpaper
- I forgot my iTunes Password
- How fast is my Mac?
- How much memory does my Mac have?
- How much free disk storage is available?
- What is my Mac serial number?
- What OS version is this?
- How much iCloud storage do I have?
- Open Mail application
- Open Safari
- Open Messages
- Open the website for OSXDaily.com
- Open the webpage (site name or site URL)
- Send a message to (name) saying (message)
- Open the Documents folder
- Open the Pictures folder
- Show me files named “screen shot”
- Show me files from yesterday
- Show me image files from last week
- Show me documents from two days ago
- Show me what I was working on yesterday
- Show me my music
- Play (song name) in iTunes
- What song is playing?
- Skip this song
- Remind me to call (name) in 20 minutes
- Show me pictures from last October
- Show me my photos from Hawaii